# Why should I create custom ConfigurationSection for my configs

Tags: c#, .net

It's been a while since I've been ever using `System.Configuration` namespace (writing custom `ConfigurationSection`) to create configuration for my own classes.

I suddenly remembered that both creating configuration classes and then usage of those classes looks extremely "old-fashioned" and awkward (i.e. no generics (implicit casts from `object` everywhere)). Besides good practice is that configuration element classes are parsed into logical classes (i.e. `JobConfigurationElement` is transformed into `Job` class).

That brings me to a questions "what are real benefits of using `ConfigurationSection` and `app.config` (`web.config`) and not just deserializing configuration from file into some classes?".

I could think of just some specific situations like IIS can automatically react on changes in configuration by restarting the application pool, but that's something one may not even wish, and certainly not relevant for other types of application (windows, wpf, etc).

Comment: You don't have to. I often use INI as my go-to format for storing configuration.

Comment: That's just how the original configuration system was designed and it might come from other programming languages. You can see that it is abandoned in .NET Core and ASP.NET Core.